# Using acts_as_recommendable for a production site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I was looking for ways to include recommendations in my application. I came to know about acts_as_recommendable plugin. I would like to know your experiences while using it in your application.
I would like to specifically know about

- Accuracy
- Pitfalls

and any other stuff you would like to point out

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used AAR for a while without problems; it'll be as accurate as that data that you can feed it, but for general recommendation engines I think it's great.

I recommend that you pre-calculate the recommended models; each day (or hour) run a rake task that calculates the recommended data for each of your models, store those, and that's what you display to the users. Otherwise it can be a drag on performance (but may not be if small datasets).